# FUN.VALUE missing when using vapply

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply a function over a list multiple times to extract the html from those urls, but when I tried to do that using vapply I got an error associated with the `FUN,VALUE` argument. I've the urls, and I want to parse them through the `rvest::html_nodes`, but this latter function doesn't accept lists, so lapply doesn't work.

```
library(xml2)

mat <- c("204554", "204521")
x <- vapply(paste0("https://www.camara.leg.br/deputados/", mat), read_html)
```

gives me an error

```
Error in vapply(paste0("https://www.camara.leg.br/deputados/", mat), read_html): 
  argument "FUN.VALUE" is missing, with no default
```

I tried some answers that I found in other topics but I couldn't resolve the problem.

Comment: I think you probably want to use `lapply` and then use it again to call `html_nodes` on each element of the resulting list. (If you examine the docs at `?vapply` you can read all about the `FUN.VALUE` argument, where it discusses the fact that all return values must match the length *and* type of what you specify, which may be problematic since `read_html` returns a list. So just use `lapply`.)

Comment: ...so it seems `vapply` will work in this particular example if you supply `FUN.VALUE = vector("list",2)`, but that seems overly strict to me, particularly when scraping a web site. I would just stick to `lapply`.

Comment: `?vapply` always requires three arguments unlike `lapply` or `sapply` and usually used for simplified structures (i.e., vector/matrix/array) and not lists.

Comment: I think “overly strict” may be good in this case? Adds a safety net if something goes wrong. @joran Do you want to turn your comments into an answer before it’s stolen ;)

Comment: @joran the problem with using lapply is that I want to use ```R x %>% html_nodes(...)``` and It answers me with an error ```R Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "list" ```

Comment: @HectorHaffenden Yeah, I dunno, `vapply` seems unnecessary to me in this particular instance, but that mostly a judgement call. My sense is that if `read_html` isn't going to return a list of length 2, probably something else has thrown an error anyway.

Comment: @JohnP.S. That's why I recommended simply doing `y <- lapply(x,html_nodes)`, and using `vapply` isn't going to fix that problem anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vapply tries to coerce the results of your function (`read_html`) to the type that you specify in FUN.VALUE. for example, if you want all the results to be given in a character vector, you can use

`FUN.VALUE = character ()`

If you would rather have the results separated, try `lapply` instead of `vapply`, which will return a list with the elements separated.

Comment: I'm still getting an error, but another one, look ```R Error in vapply(paste0("https://www.camara.leg.br/deputados/", mat), read_html,  : 
  values must be length 0,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2```